Primed summation in Microsoft Word
How can I type a "primed summation", shown in the following image, with Microsoft Word? I'm looking for an answer working on Word 2016 or Word 2021.

I'm currently using Word 2016. Right-clicking on the summation symbol, an item named "Change Limit Locations" appears, which when clicked on moves the upper limit to a good location for the prime symbol, but unfortunately it also changes the location of the lower limit.

Using an answer on the TeX SE website, I achieved this

in Word 2021, which is how Word renders the LaTeX expression \sum_{i=1}^{10}{\vphantom{\sum}}' f(x).
It's not a perfect solution, especially because the space between the summation sign and the prime is somewhat excessive. So far, I haven't been able to reduce the space.
